# android Studio: Bluetooth Discovery doesnt work on Android 10 anymore?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-version

So i'm building an app which has a built in bluetooth-discovery functionality. Now i'm trying it out on 2 different phones:

- Phone 1: Mi 9T Pro / Androidversion: 9  = works perfectly fine
- Phone2: POCO F2 PRO / Androidversion: 10 = doesnt work at all

The thing is when I try it out on Phone 1 the console shows me that the discovery process has started and shows me which devices are close by, like this:

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:6873263 intent:Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.google.android.packageinstaller (has extras) }
I/System.out: Discoverybool was set to: true
D/MainActivity: onReceive: Action Found
D/MainActivity: onReceive: null: 9C:20:7B:CD:EF:75
D/MainActivity: onReceive: Action Found
D/MainActivity: onReceive: POCO: 98:F6:21:C0:2E:FF
D/MainActivity: onReceive: Action Found
    onReceive: lieberto: 04:ED:33:63:9E:39
D/MainActivity: onReceive: Action Found
    onReceive: MEDION TV: 70:54:B4:19:31:65
D/MainActivity: onReceive: Action Found
```

But when I try it out on Phone 2: it stops right here and doesn't show any devices:

```
D/MainActivity: btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired Devices
I/System.out: Discoverybool was set to: true
```

Does anyone have any idea where the problem might be? Thanks in advance for every answer!

Here is my code:

Android.Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.fernsteuerung">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="NameOfApp"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

        >
        <activity android:name=".HistoryActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".TerminalActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".RemoteControl" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".ChooseActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Discovery function and relevant Broadcasting functions:

```
 public void btnDiscover(View view)
    {


        //Checken ob Bluetooth an ist
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null)  // Wenn das Gerät keinen Bluetooth Adapter hat
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"enableDisableBT: Does not have Bluetooth capabilities");
        }
        if(!(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())) // Wenn Bluetooth ausgeschaltet ist
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"enableDisableBT: enabling BT.");
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBTIntent);

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }


        Log.d(TAG,"btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired Devices");


        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
        {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG,"btnDiscover:Cancelling discovery.");
            //Checkt ob die Berechtigungen im Manifest für BT vorliegen
            checkBTPermissions();


            //start discovery again
           mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            //scann(mBluetoothAdapter,30);
            //System.out.println("scann1 was aufgerufen");
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3,discoverDevicesIntent);


        }

        if(!(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()))
        {
            //another check
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            //scann(mBluetoothAdapter,30);
            //System.out.println("scann2 wurde aufgerufen");
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3,discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
        discoverybool = true;
        System.out.println("Discoverybool was set to: " + discoverybool);


    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void checkBTPermissions() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            int permissionCheck = this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
            permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
            if (permissionCheck != 0) {

                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.");
        }
    }
```

Relevant Broadcasts:

```
    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch(state){
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };








    //Bluetooth Broadcoast receiver für den Button
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {

                int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE,BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch(mode)
                {
                    //Wenn das Device in Discoverable Mode ist
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG,"mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled.");
                        break;

                    //Wenn das Device nicht im discoverable mode ist:
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG,"mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                        Log.d(TAG,"mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Not able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Log.d(TAG,"mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting...");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Log.d(TAG,"mBroadcastReceiver2:Connected.");
                        break;

                }


            }
        }
    };










    //Broadcast Receiver 3 für discover devices list

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG,"onReceive: Action Found");

            if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND))
            {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);




                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());

                if(device.getName() != null)
                    {
                       
                        if(device.getName().contains("HC")) {
                            if(mBTDevices.size() < 1 ) {
                                mBTDevices.add(device);
                                mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, mBTDevices);
                                lvNewDevices.setAdapter((mDeviceListAdapter));
                            }
                        }
                    }

            }

            /*else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Entered the Finished ");
                System.out.println("Entered the Finished");
            }

             */

        }




    };
```

Class DeviceListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.fernsteuerung;


import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevices;
    private int  mViewResourceId;

    public DeviceListAdapter(Context context, int tvResourceId, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices){
        super(context, tvResourceId,devices);
        this.mDevices = devices;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mViewResourceId = tvResourceId;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

        BluetoothDevice device = mDevices.get(position);

        if (device != null) {
            TextView deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceName);
            TextView deviceAdress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceAddress);

            if (deviceName != null) {
                deviceName.setText(device.getName());
            }
            if (deviceAdress != null) {
                deviceAdress.setText(device.getAddress());
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BLe and you are acting as BLEClient then you can change the setMtu() method. as you call it you should received the confirmation in onMtuChanged() overrided method , but sometimes in Android 10 you not received the confirmation in onMtuChanged() overrided method. because you setting too hight mtu just try with 512 mtu.

Hope that will work in Android 10.

Comment: im really sorry but i dont understand. what do you mean bei setMtu method. Im not using such a method in my code

Answer (score 0):

From API 29, Google requires LOCATION group permission to use some Bluetooth function. So you will need to add some tag to Android Manifest, and DON'T forget to request these permissions at RUNTIME.

I don't remember exactly which location is needed, so you can add all 3 following, so that Bluetooth functions will work.:

- android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION